# Replace breakline with value

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
let someText = "Hi THIS IS MY TEXT AND I WANT IT CENTRED NOT ON THE TOP OF THE TEXTAREA"; //This would be replaced with your textarea value
let stringSplit = someText.split("\n");

if (stringSplit.length < 8) {
  //Add enough items to be 8 rows
  for (let x = stringSplit.length; x < 8; x++) {
    stringSplit.push("");
  }
}

//replace the 8th row value with your name
stringSplit[7] = "YourName";

//Join the array back into a string separated by newline between each element value
someText = stringSplit.join("\n");
//Set your textarea value = someText
console.log(someText);
```

With this code I am able to add value on the 8th row, but the problem is that my text will be like this:

```
    EXEMPLE OF TEXT






       VALUE(8throw)
```

Instead of

```
            /n
            /n
            /n
        MY TEXT


       Value(8th row)
```

I want to let my text centred , and the value to be on the 8th row, instead of having my text on the top of the textarea, an my value on the bottom.
I want to replace the 3 breakline by my text to make something like this.

```
\n \n \n Mytext \n \n \n Value
```

What I want to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gveLo.png)

Comment: Try to use CSS. Add div, classes and ids to your texts then it will be easier to design

Answer (score 1):

Add to the beginning and the end of the array alternatively:

```js
let someText = "Example text";
let stringSplit = someText.split("\n");
for (let x = stringSplit.length; x < 8; x++) {
  if (x % 2 == 0) {
    stringSplit.unshift("");
  } else {
    stringSplit.push("");
  }
}
stringSplit[7] = "Last line";
console.log(stringSplit.join("\n"));
```

But yes, if you're doing this solely for the visual effect, you should look into proper CSS formatting.